# How do i incorporate this formula into my python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cdf

I am new to Python and trying to figure a way to input numbers to a mathematical formula.

Mathematical formula as shown:
[image]

I have developed based on the above formula, but not fully sure why it cant work.

```
def cumulative_function():
    alpha = 0.05
    fx_value = 5
    variable_a = -100
    k = 2
    cdf_formula = alpha * (fx_value * (a) + fx_value * (k - 2 * (alpha) + fx * (k - alpha) + fx_value * (value_x)))
    return cdf_formula

cdf = cumulative_function()
print (f"value is: {cdf}")
```

*EDIT:
How do I insert the infinity ('...') in the formula to my program?
Would appreciate anyone who can help me out:)

Comment: For infinity: ```float('inf')```. Also, your variables are not defined. So you get an error

Comment: Please give an example of the formula with specific values for `a, k and fx`.

Comment: @quamrana Done added those

Comment: Ok, I get an error when I run your code: `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

fx(a) is not fx *(a) but actually a function to which you are passing a value 'a'

- for example let fx()=x*2+x
- then fx(a) will be a*2+a
- fx(5) will be 5*2+5=10+15